# values map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend

- const {memberList} = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) =>
  state.member.memberList)

  ```
         <div>
             {
                    memberList.length > 0 &&
                     <Table stackable>
                         <Table.Header>
                             <Table.Row>
                                 <Table.HeaderCell>Id</Table.HeaderCell>
                                 <Table.HeaderCell>İsim Soyisim</Table.HeaderCell>
                                 <Table.HeaderCell>Email</Table.HeaderCell>
                                 <Table.HeaderCell>Son Durum</Table.HeaderCell>
                                 <Table.HeaderCell>RDC Link</Table.HeaderCell>
                             </Table.Row>
                         </Table.Header>

               <Table.Body>
                   {
                      memberList.map((memberItem : any) => (
                           <Table.Row key={memberItem.id}>
                             {console.log("id" + memberItem.id)}
                             <Table.Cell>{memberItem.id}</Table.Cell>
                               <Table.Cell>{memberItem.userName}</Table.Cell>
                               <Table.Cell>{memberItem.email}</Table.Cell>
                               <Table.Cell>{memberItem.lastStatement}</Table.Cell>
                               <Table.Cell>{memberItem.rdcLink}</Table.Cell>
                           </Table.Row>
                       ))
                   }

               </Table.Body>
           </Table>
       }
   </div>
  ```

I get an error. typeerror: memberlist.map is not a function

Comment: could you show me member list data structure\

Comment: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: '', method: 'post', data: '{"Name":""}', headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data:
MemberList: Array(5)
0: {id: , userName: '', email: '', lastStatement: '.', lastState: '', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
isRecordedProfile: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
status: 200
statusText: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: looks like the memberList is undefined. could you show the reducer for that state and  action creator

Answer (score 1):

If memberList is an object then you should use Object.keys(memberList) to be able to use the map method.

`Object.keys(memberList).map( key => { return memberList[key].id })`